# Error: Assertion failed: !_debugDuringDeviceUpdate is not true flutter

Tags: flutter-web

I am facing this error when using adding some widgets like ListView to a flutter web project
I never faced it before when working with android

```
    Exception has occurred.
"Error: Assertion failed: file:///D:/Android/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/mouse_tracking.dart:312:12
!_debugDuringDeviceUpdate
is not true
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:23584/dart_sdk.js:4328:11)
    at Object.assertFailed (http://localhost:23584/dart_sdk.js:4275:15)
    at mouse_tracking.MouseTracker.new.[_deviceUpdatePhase] (http://localhost:23584/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4940:61)
    at http://localhost:23584/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4998:33
    at mouse_tracking.MouseTracker.new.[_monitorMouseConnection] (http://localhost:23584/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4935:7)
    at mouse_tracking.MouseTracker.new.updateWithEvent (http://localhost:23584/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4997:36)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:23584/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:5943:45)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerEvent] (http://localhost:23584/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:257:14)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_flushPointerEventQueue] (http://localhost:23584/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:229:35)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerDataPacket] (http://localhost:23584/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:213:65)
    at Object._invoke1 (http://localhost:23584/dart_sdk.js:175453:7)
    at _engine.EngineWindow.new.invokeOnPointerDataPacket (http://localhost:23584/dart_sdk.js:171307:15)
    at _engine.PointerBinding.__.[_onPointerData] (http://localhost:23584/dart_sdk.js:158211:24)
    at http://localhost:23584/dart_sdk.js:158585:26
    at http://localhost:23584/dart_sdk.js:158557:16
    at http://localhost:23584/dart_sdk.js:158310:11"
```

I looked everywhere but with no clues
thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the piece of code which produces this error. [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/flutter) is a good place to show case this error.

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes, assets need re-rendering in order to update dynamically. So,
**Instead of hot reloading, try hot restarting**, or close the app and rebuild it.

Comment: Any ideas if that doesn't work?

Comment: It's not the solution because how do you know in production that sometime you should start your app with restarting your app? It's pointless.
I see this problem with the last upgraded flutter version when the associated ticket on github has closed about couple months ago but the problem is still here.

Comment: just restart android studio ,hahhaha

Answer (score 12):

I was also facing the same issue. But in my case I noticed there was another error which said

```
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
```

Adding these two lines to ListView should fix the error:

```
scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
shrinkWrap: true,
```

Comment: shrink wrap helped in my case...

Answer (score 2):

Can you please share the code? Because I also faced the same error but I have resolved it.
Apparently, I was using a Row() widget in the `Trailing` of my ListTile() widget. So I just add the following property in my Row() widget

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min
```

But, I still suggest you please share the piece of code too which is throwing that error so that someone suggests an answer more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a row and needed to put `Expaned()` around the list view

Answer (score 0):

I had this assertion failure happening because I was using a `MouseRegion` subtree, where the `onEnter`/`onExit` handlers were throwing an uncaught exception specific to my app. Once the app's exception occurred, this assertion failure occurred, and after that no clickable element will show the proper cursor.

Once I got rid of the uncaught exception coming form `onEnter`/`onExit` handlers, this assertion failure stopped happening.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84241#issuecomment-1236344314.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentially swapping a `Column` for a `Row` might also stir up errors like these.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to enlarge the screen with the size property of the Container

```
Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(_buildContext!).size.width 
)
```